# Pandas Apply returns a Series instead of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The goal of following code is to go through each row in **df_label**, extract **app1** and **app2** names, filter **df_all** using those two names, concatenate the result and return it as a dataframe. Here is the code:

```
def create_dataset(se):
    # extracting the names of applications
    app1 = se.app1
    app2 = se.app2
    
    # extracting each application from df_all
    df1 = df_all[df_all.workload == app1]
    df1.columns = df1.columns + '_0'
    df2 = df_all[df_all.workload == app2]
    df2.columns = df2.columns + '_1'
    
    # combining workloads to create the pairs dataframe
    df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    display(df3)
    return df3

df_pairs = pd.DataFrame()
df_label.apply(create_dataset, axis=1)
#df_pairs = df_pairs.append(df_label.apply(create_dataset, axis=1))
```

I would like to append all dataframes returned from apply. However, while `display(df3)` shows the correct dataframe, when returned from function, it's not a dataframe anymore and it's a series. A series with one element and that element seems to be the whole dataframe. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you select a single column, you'll get a Series instead of a DataFrame so `df1` and `df2` will both be series.

However, concatenating them on `axis=1` should produce a DataFrame (whereas combining them on `axis=0` would produce a series). For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
df1 = df['a']
df2 = df['b']
```

---

```
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
>>> pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=0)
0    1
1    2
0    3
1    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks Derek for the answer. When I use `display(df3)` inside the function (shown above in the code), it displays the correct dataframe. However, when I `return df3` in the next line, what I get is a series. This is what confuses me.

Comment: @Maz what do you get when you add the line `print(type(df3))` before the line `display(df3)`? that will tell you conclusively what you have. `display(df3)` will look the same if df3 is a one column dataframe or a series